# Different python environments used in debug and run mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my Ubuntu machine I have two Python interpreters, native Python and conda. When I run a script in run more in Visual Studio Code, the native Python interpreter is used and in debug mode, the conda interpreter is used. Where does this difference come and how to make the run mode use also conda interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is to auto-activate the base conda environment:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base True
```